# Vendoring problem from Opencensus Libraries for Golang

Tags: go, godeps, glide-golang, govendor

I'm having problem while vendoring my go-project. Tried with both glide and go-dep - getting same problem.

`$ go get -u go.opencensus.io` gives the following error:

```
package go.opencensus.io/opencensus-go: unrecognized import path "go.opencensus.io/opencensus-go" (https fetch: Get https://go.opencensus.io/opencensus-go?go-get=1: dial tcp <some-ip>: i/o timeout)
```

Github link of this package - https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried setting a proxy to shell

```
export http_proxy=http://104.248.231.49:8080/
export https_proxy=http://104.248.231.49:8080/
```

And then it worked.